# How to use Spring to mange mulitple "runtime noticed" database connection with different jdbc(or hibernate?)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I have a web application access to a database which it's connection info(connection string,username,pwd) are enter by the user at runtime.

thus, I can not notice any information in deploy time.

The system is supposed to support multiple type of database with different jdbc

How can I manage this situation using spring/hibernate(I doubt that hibernate can handle this  because the data structure is known in runtime)??

Comment: Do you intend to use the user entered data sources only once or store it for future usage too?

Comment: For future usage too,actually i am using the value to from database Validate forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an approach similar to the one described [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

Basically just subclass AbstractRoutingDataSource and override the method determineTargetDataSource (if you need to create the datasources from within your application) or determineCurrentLookupKey (if your datasources are going to be already created in the app server).

In the determineTargetDataSource  method you can return whatever datasource you need, or create a new one if need be.